# Add two more columns to csv file based on matching values of other csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two csv files

csv1:

[image]

csv2:

[image]

What i need to process is:

Get each value of column **c** of csv1 file and match it with column **number** of csv2.

If any row of csv2 matches with that number then add a new column **c_text** into csv1 that will contain value of **text** column for matching row of csv2

Repeat above process for column **d** of csv1 and add a new column **d_text** into csv1

Here is what i need at the end

[image]

Am new to pandas. How can i do this using pandas.

Comment: pd.merge() is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply()`:

```
csv1['c_text'] = csv1['c'].apply(lambda x: csv2[csv2['number']==x]['text'].values[0])
csv1['d_text'] = csv1['d'].apply(lambda x: csv2[csv2['number']==x]['text'].values[0])
```

Yields:

```
   a  b    c    d c_text d_text
0  1  4  101  201   val1   val4
1  2  5  105  202   val2   val5
2  3  6  107  203   val3   val6
```

In terms of an option using `merge()`, this will yield the same output:

```
csv1 = csv1.merge(csv2, left_on='c', right_on='number', how='left')
csv1 = csv1.merge(csv2, left_on='d', right_on='number', how='left')
csv1 = csv1.rename(columns={'text_x': 'c_text', 'text_y': 'd_text'})[['a','b','c','d','c_text','d_text']]
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using apply over merge in this situation? Honestly curious

Comment: IMHO it's more readable, but I will admit it's less stable in the sense that it assumes each value in `c` or `d` of `csv1` will have a corresponding row in the `number` column of `cv2`, otherwise an error will be thrown. I will add a `merge()` option as an alternative, as for large dataframes it will most likely outperform `apply()` in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will do the trick:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c':[101, 105, 107], 'd':[201, 202, 203]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'number': [101, 105, 107, 201, 202, 203, 205, 2010, 310], 'text': ["val_{x}".format(x=y + 1) for y in range(9)]})

df1

   a  b    c    d
0  1  4  101  201
1  2  5  105  202
2  3  6  107  203

df2

   number   text
0     101  val_1
1     105  val_2
2     107  val_3
3     201  val_4
4     202  val_5
5     203  val_6
6     205  val_7
7    2010  val_8
8     310  val_9
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='c', right_on='number', how='left')

merged

   a  b    c    d  number   text
0  1  4  101  201     101  val_1
1  2  5  105  202     105  val_2
2  3  6  107  203     107  val_3

output = merged.merge(df2, left_on='d', right_on='number', how='left')[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'text_x', 'text_y']]

output

   a  b    c    d text_x text_y
0  1  4  101  201  val_1  val_4
1  2  5  105  202  val_2  val_5
2  3  6  107  203  val_3  val_6
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the merge functionality of Pandas. Assuming you have imported the Pandas module with the shorthand name like `import pandas as pd`, then:

```
csv1_with_text_col = pd.merge(csv1, csv2, left_on='c', right_on='number', how='left')
```

This will give you a new dataframe, csv1_with_text_col, with the columns from csv2 merged into csv1 where csv1['c'] == csv2['number']. Additionally, by specifying `how='left'`, only rows from the left dataframe, csv1, will be kept.

You can then merge this new dataframe, csv1_with_text_col, with csv2 again but with `left_on='d'`.